# scope in class python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a class :

```
class Difference:
    def __init__(self,a1):
      self.a1=a1
    def  computeDifference(self):
      d0=max([max(self.a1)-i for i in self.a1])
      return d0
      maximumDifference=d0
```

Now when i try to access the class like bellow getting bellow error:

```
_ = input().strip()
a = [int(e) for e in input().strip().split(' ')]
d = Difference(a)
d.computeDifference()
print(d.maximumDifference)
```

error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "q.py", line 2, in 
>        class Difference:
>        File "q.py", line 8, in Difference
>         maximumDifference=d0
>        NameError: name 'd0' is not defined

what went wrong?

Comment: you never told pytho what `d0` is and when you try to set `maximumDifference` to `d0` python throws you the error. Define `d0` in your class`Difference` to avoid the error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A few things:

1. You need to define what `d0` is before you can assign it to `maximumDifference`.
2. And even if you do define `d0` and try to assign it to  `maximumDifference` it won't be reached because that line is after the `return` statemen.
3. incorrect indentation but that might be just how you posted your question. I edited your question to fix the indentation error

you can do something like this to fix the above problems:

```
def  computeDifference(self):
        d0=max([max(self.a1)-i for i in self.a1])
        self.maximumDifference=d0
        return d0
```

The above code would work But it is **NOT good practice to define attribute outside of __init__**. It is **better to define class attributes inside of __init__**

```
class Difference:

    def __init__(self,a1):
      self.a1=a1
      self.maximumDifference = self.computeDifference()
    def  computeDifference(self):
        d0=max([max(self.a1)-i for i in self.a1])
        return d0
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is with indentation. Python code must be well indented in order to work properly. Try:

```
class Difference:

    def __init__(self,a1):
      self.a1=a1

    def  computeDifference(self):
        d0=max([max(self.a1)-i for i in self.a1])
        self.maximumDifference=d0
        return d0
```

Also the line `maximumDifference=d0` would never be reached as it was placed after a return and, even if it was, your code wouldn't work since you're using only locally. To store and use `maximumDifference` outside that function you should store it in `self.maximumDifference` like the example above.